# Чудеса в решете

Tags: фразеология, смысл

Думаю, эту поговорку знают все. Более того, я прочитала, что целиком она звучит так:
**Чудеса в решете — дыр много, а выскочить некуда.**

Вот только мне совершенно не понятен ее *изначальный смысл.*
Сейчас "чудесами в решете" все чаще называют всевозможные невероятные выдумки.
А почему, собственно, они в решете и почему им надо куда-то выскакивать через дырки?

Comment: Вы уверены, что это не искусственное продолжение?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Значение поговорки связано со старым способом гадания на рынке. На дно решета насыпались разноцветные зёрна бобовых, заведомо не проходящие в отверстия; решето встряхивалось, и зёрна складывались в случайный узор. По нему умельцы толковали за деньги судьбу, сочиняя изысканные небылицы. Откуда вторая часть поговорки, могу только предположить. Недоверчивый "клиент" мог бы удивлённо сказать о "чудесах", дипломатично отнеся своё удивление к свойствам решета, а на самом деле намекая на то, что ему за его деньги нафантазировали. Либо кто-то из присутствующих мог так сказать.

Comment: Описание гадания. Как-то не совпадает.  
>Гадание на решете - Это гадание употребляется главным образом при пропаже домашних вещей или животных, для того, чтобы "открыть вора". Сначала нужно подготовить решето: ворожейки сеют этим решетом снег, а потом вытрясают его при лунном свете... Берут решето, утверждают его на указательном пальце, вытягивают руку в сторону и потом начинают причитывать имена тех людей, на кого падает подозрение. Если при чьем имени посетитель и ворожея заметят, что решето повернулось, тот почитается вором.

Может, есть исторический источник хотя бы 19 века?

Comment: Ссылаются на Москву 17-18 века:
http://frazbook.ru/2009/01/15/chudesa-v-reshete/

Comment: Источник: В.Мокиенко, "Загадки русской фразеологии". То есть это  пересказ. Хотелось бы подревнее книжечку.

Comment: Ответ от @Alex_ander. совершенно правильный. Здесь насмешка, ирония по ассоциации с невежественным гаданием. Схожее: ЭТО НАША БАБУШКА В РЕШЕТЕ УВИДЕЛА!

Comment: Про вторую часть (насчет обманутого клиента) ничего сказать не могу, сомнительно как-то, тут больше с клеткой ассоциируются.  
А вот про гадания зерном - да, неоднократно про то слышал.

Answer (score 1):

Меня ответ Alex_ander, верный по сути, тоже не совсем устроил в деталях и комментариях. Что гадание - да, а вот остальные уже надо бы уточнить.

Дело в том, что гадание на воров - это лишь один из способов использования решета как гадательного инструмента. Применялся более в западной Европе, и вроде бы - Азии.

На Руси по свидетельству различных источников все было поставлено на более широкую ногу, появлялись в решете и другие, куда более значительные, чудеса.

> В России этот способ гадания был чрезвычайно распространен, но
>   достаточно сильно отличался от «классического». В XVI—XVIII веках на
>   рыночных площадях Москвы можно было увидеть гадальщиков, насыпавших в
>   решета разноцветные зерна чечевицы, бобов, гороха или миндаля.
>   Встряхивая решето, они по расположению зерен предсказывали будущее.
>   Чтобы придать гаданию большую магическую силу, они что-то нашептывали,
>   выкрикивали, жестикулировали. Стремясь выманить побольше денег,
>   гадальщики сочиняли самые невероятные и фантастические истории,
>   предрекая простодушным слушателям счастливую женитьбу, нежданное
>   богатство или необычные события и приключения, короче — всякие чудеса.
>   Такие шарлатанские предсказания с насмешкой назывались чудесами в
>   решете.

http://frazbook.ru/2009/01/15/chudesa-v-reshete/

По мне так все логично и исчерпывающе.

Теперь о "второй части" поговорки. Трудно признать её канонической, но в чем-то она логична. Приписывание решету магических свойств не случайно. Своеобразный и эффективный процесс засталял думать о чудесах даже привыкших к мистике людей средневековья. Если решето умеет отделять сор от муки, то почему оно не может отделять вора от честного? А там и до настоящих чудес недалеко. И вот это вот "дыр много..." - вполне подходит для выражения представлений о мистических свойствах решета.

*(Я написал про просеивание муки через решето. Строго говоря, муку сеяли через сито. Но сито - это всего лишь особый тип решета, с мелкими ячейками. Здесь это не принципиально).*

Answer (score 0):

Бенедикт Нурсийский! Первое его чудо, в начале карьеры святого, в молодости - он склеил, починил молитвой разбившееся глиняное решето. Описано Григорием Великим в житии Бенедикта. Диалоги Григория Двоеслова были читаемы на Руси, вполне допустимое происхождение поговорки.

Comment: К этому подошло бы "чудо с решетом", а у нас — "чудеса в решете".

Comment: Карьера святого? Решето из глины? Молитва починившая решето... Это же — логарифмической линейкой по гвоздю.

Comment: См: http://simvol-veri.ru/xp/jitie-prepodobnogo-otca-nashego-venedikta.html  Он восстановил разбитые ночвы  - лоток или сосуд, подобный лотку, употребляемый для очищения жита и прочих земледельческих потребностей.